# How to use max in a lambda function applied to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to apply a lambda function to a pandas Dataframe that return the difference between each row and the max of that column.

It can be easily achieved by using a separate variable and setting that to the max of the column, but I'm curious how it can be done in a single line of code.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'measure': [i for i in range(0,10)]
})

col_max = df.measure.max()
df['diff_from_max'] = df.apply(lambda x: col_max - x['measure'], axis=1)
```

Comment: `df['diff_from_max'] = df['measure'].max() - df['measure']` you dont need apply for this

Comment: Thanks, @anky,  I need to use apply as it's a simplified version of the question I'm trying to solve. I have to call other functions as part of my lambda function and use apply to use value from other columns including max of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually do

```
max_df=df.max()-df

df=df.join(max_df.add_prefix('diff_max_')
```

To fix your code since the apply is not need here

```
col_max = df.measure.max()
df['diff_from_max'] = col_max-df['measure']
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still two line! :)

Comment: output is exactly what I have in ```df```. I'm only looking for a single line solution with apply, if it's possible.

Comment: @MehdiZare df.apply(lambda x: df.measure.max() - x['measure'], axis=1)?

Comment: Thanks! Now I see what I missed, I used x instead of df to get the max in lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I think apply() is not required here. You can simply use following line :

```
df['diff_from_max'] = df['measure'].max() - df['measure']
```